# Activate or deactivate EventHandler using a variable

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, event-handling

Is there any way to merge these voids into one? I have a lot of controls that use the same event and during execution are activated and deactivated

```
private void activate()
{
   tb1.TextChanged += eventFil;
   tb2.TextChanged += eventFil;
   cb1.CheckStateChanged += eventFil;
   cb2.CheckStateChanged += eventFil;            
}
private void deactivate()
{
   tb1.TextChanged -= eventFil;
   tb2.TextChanged -= eventFil;
   cb1.CheckStateChanged -= eventFil;
   cb2.CheckStateChanged -= eventFil;            
}
```

Like this

```
private void activate(operator aux)
{
   tb1.TextChanged aux eventFil;
   tb2.TextChanged aux eventFil;
   cb1.CheckStateChanged aux eventFil;
   cb2.CheckStateChanged aux eventFil;            
}
```

Or like this

```
private void activate()
{            
   aux(c => c += eventFiltre);
}

private void deactivate()
{            
   aux(c => c -= eventFiltre);
}

private void aux(Action<EventHandler> action)
{
   action(tb1.TextChanged);
   ....
}
```

Comment: Why don't you have a "should execute" flag that's evaluated in the event handler instead? Then you have activation/deactivation at the flip of a switch ( = setting a bool to true / false )

Comment: Too many `aux`s in the last snippet, but anyway: Would shifting the point of evaluation to the event handler be an option for you? If yes, I can write an answer. As the question is right now, I won't because it doesn't seem to solve your problem - which I feel is an x-y ...

Answer (score 1):

An alternative that solves the underlying problem, rather than the question at hand: Introduce a Handler-Switch.

Easiest to explain in code:

```
class YourClass
{

    private bool CanHandleTextChanged = true;

    // It has probably specialized EventArgs, but you get the gist ...
    // This would be "eventFil" in your example
    private void TextChangedHandler ( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        if (!CanHandleTextChanged) return;

        // ... handle TextChanged Event
    }

}
```

Then you can activate or deactivate the event handling by simply setting the bool field `CanHandleTextChanged` to true or false.

Comment: Provided that event handling should be turned of for all controls, this is the best and cleanest solution.

Comment: @PalleDue That's what it looked like. All Controls were registered / deregistered for the same event handler in the question's example code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one method like this

```
//you can pass true or false
private void Operate(bool isActivation)
{
   if(isActivation)
   {
       tb1.TextChanged += eventFil;
       tb2.TextChanged += eventFil;
       cb1.CheckStateChanged += eventFil;
       cb2.CheckStateChanged += eventFil;  
   }
   else
   {
       tb1.TextChanged -= eventFil;
       tb2.TextChanged -= eventFil;
       cb1.CheckStateChanged -= eventFil;
       cb2.CheckStateChanged -= eventFil;
   }      
}
```

Comment: `value = "activate"` is an assignment operation ...

Comment: you can change string to bool and pass true or false !?

Comment: Then you can have two methods, as well. Some people might even argue, having two sperarate methods is "cleaner" ... so it is not _really_ so much of an improvement.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible do that because += and -= only can appear on an assignement. You can have all in one method for better maintenance, but with two sentences for each event:

```
private void EnableEvents(bool enabled = true)
{
   if (enabled)
   {
      tb1.TextChanged += eventFil;
      tb2.TextChanged += eventFil;
      cb1.CheckStateChanged += eventFil;
      cb2.CheckStateChanged += eventFil;            
   }
   else
   {
      tb1.TextChanged -= eventFil;
      tb2.TextChanged -= eventFil;
      cb1.CheckStateChanged -= eventFil;
      cb2.CheckStateChanged -= eventFil;            
   }
}
```